# Is *Numidius* an Ancient Roman name?

Tags: classical-latin, names, roman-culture

Is Numidius an Ancient Roman name (probably a *nomen gentilis*) or is it spurious and caused by corruption of other names?

What I have found so far:

- The name Ummidius (that is clearly and unmistakably attested) can be corrupted to Numidius
- There also is a name Numisius that is easily mistyped (on a modern keyboard) as Numidius
- There is a cognomen Numidicus (for victories against the Numidians).

Comment: Where have you seen *Numidius*? What makes you ask this? The question is interesting, I'd just like to know where it comes from.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I found the name in my memory and put it into some search engines, giving results like a redirect to Ummidius on the English wikipedia.

Comment: It sounds remotely familiar to me, too, but I can't remember where I would have seen it. Idle curiosity is always sufficient motivation for a question; I merely wondered if there was more behind this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are various epigraphical references of ***Numidius*** as a *nomen*:

> *CIL* VIII 23074 (Ain Batria): *Aurelius Numidius P[3]nsi[3]*
>
> *CIL* X 3824 (Capua): *Cn(aeum) Numidium / Astragalum*
>
> *CIL* XIV 3627 (Tivoli): *C(aius) Numidius Qua/dratus*
>
> *ILCV* 297 (Santa Maria Capua Vetere): *Murrius / Numidius*
>
> *PanDeser* 64 (Berenice): *C(aius) Numidius Eros*

In *CIL* VIII 5301 (Calama) is used as a *praenomen* (*Numidius Marius*), while  *ILAlg* I 2071 (Madauros) records it as a *cognomen* of *Q(uintus) Domitius Numidius*.

The most famous person to which has been attributed the *cognomen* ***Numidicus*** was [Q. Metellus Numidicus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintus_Caecilius_Metellus_Numidicus) (cfr. e.g. Cic. *Brut.* 135; Vell. 2,9,1; Val. Max. 3,8,4; Gell. 15,14,1), who fought against Jugurtha in Numidia from 109 a.C. (see also *CIL* VI 40942 [Rome] *Q(uintus) Caec[ilius L(uci) f(ilius) Metellus] / [Numidicus]*).

Other epigraphical references of that *cognomen* are:

> *CIL* VIII 15667 (Kaussat): *P(ublius) Larci/us Numidicus*
>
> *CIL* VIII 16104 (El Kef): *T(itus) Largius / Numidicus*
>
> *CIL* VIII 25660 (Chemtou): *L(ucius) Iulius / Numidicus*
>
> *IScM* V 00270 (Isaccea): *Mar]cianu[s] / [3] Cassius Numidicus*
>
> *RMD* IV 223 (?): *Ti(berius) Claudius Numidicus*

Answer (score 5):

[Edited because I didn't read the full opening post at first.]

There were people named [Numidius](https://books.google.com/books?id=e3DYAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62#v=onepage&q&f=false), but Numidicus as an agnomen (not cognomen) was attached to a very famous Roman politician, so I would bet that you were actually thinking of him.